# import custom react component library to another project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

everyone! I have problem with importing my components to another project and always bump into the error like this:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I've read tons of topics and articles with the same problem, but still don't know what's wrong here:

my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    clean: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx' ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

my project structure:

```
- src
-- shared
--- components
----- component-a
------ component-a.tsx
-- store
- index.ts
```

Here is example of my component:

```
const ComponentA: FC<ComponentAI> = (props: ComponentAI) => {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      ....
    </GlobalProvider>
  )
}
export default ComponentA
```

here is my root index.ts:

```
import ComponentA from './shared/components/componentA/componentA'
import ComponentB from './shared/components/componentA/componentB'

export default {
  ComponentA,
  ComponentB,
}
```

how I import my lib to another project:

```
import react from 'react';
import lib from 'perfectlive-metamask-toolkit';

console.log(lib.MetaMaskIntegration);

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello
      <lib.MetaMaskIntegration/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In console log i see this:

```
e => c.default.createElement(m.default, null, c.default.createElement(y, Object.assign({}, e)))
```

if I log this:

```
console.log(lib)
```

see this:

```
{
  ComponentA: (e) => {...},
  ComponentB: (e) => {...}
}
```

webpack always import my components as object, it doesn't matter if i do named import or default import. Maybe you have any ideas about that? Thank you.

Comment: What's `lib.MetaMaskIntegration`? Shouldn't be `lib.ComponentA` or `lib.ComponentB` in your demo?